# Please I keep getting this error when I try to run my flutter app

Tags: flutter

> What went wrong:  Could not determine the dependencies of task
>   ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Could not resolve all task
>   dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'. > Could
>   not find
>   io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.
>   Required by: project :app > Could not find
>   io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.
>   Required by: project :app > Could not find
>   io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.
>   Required by: project :ap

Comment: You should provide more information about your problem. Include steps to reproduce your issue. include the code of the flutter app that you are trying to run.checkout this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30573

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're on master branch and your flutter upgraded to last version.
then if the error remain delete the .gradle cache folder in youre home and applying ./gradlew cleanBuildCache in the project's android sub directory.